# How to find a coordinates transformation on $A\,\mathrm dS_2$?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I have the following 2D metrics (describing the $AdS_2$ spacetime), which are supposed to be the same in different coordinates:
\begin{align}
\mathrm ds^2 &= \mathrm dt^2 - \sin^2{\!\omega t} \, \mathrm dz^2, \tag{1} \\[12pt]
\mathrm ds^2 &= (1 + x^2) \, \mathrm d\theta^2 - \frac{1}{(1 + x^2)} \, \mathrm dx^2. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Metric (1) covers only some part of the $A\mathrm dS_2$ manifold, while metric (2) is supposed to cover the full manifold.  How could I find the coordinates' transformation $(t, z) \Rightarrow (\theta, x)$, or the reverse $(\theta, x) \Rightarrow (t, z)$ ?

---

Maybe I should go the following route.  I define this surface:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
u^2 + v^2 - w^2 = R^2,
\end{equation}
with a flat 3D metric:
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\mathrm ds^2 = \mathrm du^2 + \mathrm dv^2 - \mathrm dw^2.
\end{equation}
Here's a partial parametrization of (3), with $\omega = 1/R$:
\begin{align}
u &= R \cos{\omega t},
& v &= R \sin{\omega t} \, \cosh{\omega z},
& w &= R \sin{\omega t} \, \sinh{\omega z}.
\end{align}
Substituting this parametrization into (4) gives metric (1):
\begin{equation}
\mathrm ds^2 = \mathrm dt^2 - \sin^2 {\! \omega t} \; \mathrm dz^2.
\end{equation}
Now, I need to find another parametrization of (3) which would give metric (2).

Answer (score 0):

Doh!  I just found the answer.  It was easy with the route I described in my question.

Here's another parametrization of (3):
\begin{align}
u &= \sqrt{R^2 + x^2} \, \sin{\vartheta},
& v &= \sqrt{R^2 + x^2} \, \cos{\vartheta},
& w &= x.
\end{align}
Substituting this parametrization into (4) gives the metric (2):
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = (R^2 + x^2) \, d\vartheta^2 - \frac{R^2}{(R^2 + x^2)} \, dx^2,
\end{equation}
which is the same as (2) after a simple scale change of $\theta$ and $x$.